# linux ulimit with java does not work properly

Tags: java, linux, runtime.exec, ulimit

I run code on linux ubuntu 17.10

```
public class TestExec {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "ulimit", "-n"});
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

this code returns "unlimited"

but whenever I run command from terminal I get 1024.

Why those numbers are different?

Comment: This is not directly programming-related. I think this question might be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same result if you run the same command from the command line:

```
$ "/bin/sh" "-c" "ulimit" "-n"
unlimited
```

This is because `-c` only looks at the argument immediately following it, which is `ulimit`. The `-n` is not part of this argument, and is instead instead assigned as a positional parameter (`$0`).

To run `ulimit -n`, the `-n` needs to be part of that argument:

```
$ "/bin/sh" "-c" "ulimit -n"
1024
```

In other words, you should be using:

```
new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "ulimit -n"}
```